# Select dropdown value after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I was hoping for some guidance on an issue I am having with preserving the value in a dropdownlist after post (razor)

I have a simple page:

```
    @model testContingency.Models.ListByWardDD

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestDropDowns";
}

<h2>TestDropDowns</h2>

<div>

    @Html.DropDownList("HospModel", Model.Hospital,  new { @onchange = "ChangeHospital(this.value)" }) 
    @Html.DropDownList("WardModel", Model.Wards)

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function ChangeHospital(val) {
            window.location.href = "/PatientListByWardDD/TestDropDowns?hospID=" + val;
        }



    </script>

</div>
```

here's the controller

```
public ActionResult TestDropDowns(int? hospID)
    {
        PASInpatientRepository pasRepo = new PASInpatientRepository();
        var returnModel = new ListByWardDD();     
        var HospitalData = pasRepo.GetPatientHospitalsEnum();
        returnModel.Hospital = pasRepo.GetHopspitalListItems(HospitalData);
        var WardData = pasRepo .GetPatientWardsEnum(hospID);
        returnModel.Wards = pasRepo.GetWardListItems(WardData);
        ViewBag.HospSearch = hospID;
        return View(returnModel);
    }
```

In the controller `PASInpatientRepository()` communicates with a cache database. It passes back public IEnumerable < SelectListItem > GetHopspitalListItems. It calls stored procedures written within a cache database (same as sql stored procedures in essence). This is all working fine in its own crude way.

The issue I am having is that when I select the dropdownlist `@Html.DropDownList("HospModel", Model.Hospital,  new { @onchange = "ChangeHospital(this.value)" })` and the controller is called to refresh the Wards dropdown, I want to preserve the value I have selected in the hospital dropdown. I have tried a few different ways, but I admit, I'm a bit stuck. Most examples I found are for strongly typed.

As I mentioned, I'm new to MVC, but any advice on how to solve this issue, or suggestions on improving my code are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure what the Hospital property looks like but I'll make the assumption that each one has a unique ID.
Furthermore to bind the posted data to the view model you'll need to use forms in your view. To create the drop down list use the `DropDownListFor`-Helper. This way the data will be bound back to your Model after submitting the form.

So your view could look something like this

```
@model testContingency.Models.ListByWardDD

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestDropDowns";
}

<h2>TestDropDowns</h2>

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("TestDropDowns", "YourController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.HospitalID, Model.Hospital)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WardID, Model.Wards)
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
}    
</div>
```

Your ViewModel `testContigency.Models.ListByWardDD` must have at least the following properties

```
public class ListByWardDD {
    public int HostpitalID { get;set; }
    // the value of the SelectListItem-objects should be the hospital ID
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Hospital { get;set; }

    public int WardID { get;set; }
    // the value of the SelectListItem-objects should be the ward ID
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Wards { get;set; }
}
```

Once you post the form (for simplicity I added a button to send the form and left the javascript part out) the method TestDropDowns of your controller (which you need to fill in the BeginForm-Helper) will be called. That method expects expects an object of type ListByWardDD as a parameter and the framework will automatically populate the values for you.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestDropDowns(ListByWardDD viewModel) {
    // your code here, viewModel.HospitalID should contain the selected value
}
```

Note: After submitting the form the properties `Hospital` and `Wards` will be empty. If you need to display the form again, you need to repopulate those properties. Otherwise your dropdown lists are empty.

I tried my best to post valid code but I did not compile or test it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback. I will take onboard your suggestion to use ListFor and Lambda. But I really need to know how to reload the selected value in the hospital list after a postback. I don't really want to use javascript and Ajax if I can help. but im starting to think its unavoidable, unless someone can suggest otherwise?